# MessageKit through pods will crash iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, messagekit

I am working on an application using Swift and am trying to integrate an in-app messaging system. I planned on using 'MessageKit', but after adding it to my podfile, running 'pod update' and re-running my app, it crashes on launch. There is no error printed in the command line. Some specs: Swift 4.2, MessageKit 2.0. I am sure that MessageKit is causing this, but I have no idea why. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Swift 4.2 use following versions

```
    pod 'MessageKit',          '~> 2.0.0'
    pod 'MessageInputBar',     '~> 0.4.1'
```

Comment: How do I remove the derived data?

Comment: Please disregard that last comment, your solution works